# Creating a basic user login

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

My code has two forms that create a text field for both username and password. The php script takes the form information and sends it to the server for it to decide if the strings from the form data correspond with the username and password I want. I also have a logout button form that goes to a logout.php script which logs the user out. If I click the logout button it sends the user to my login.php script and ends the session. I can't get users to login to the website and I cant get users to go to the login.php page if I go to the site that has the logout.php. Here is my code:

Login php Code:

```
   <?php
               session_start();
               if($_SESSION['login'] == true)
               {
                header("Location:index.php");
               }
               else
               {
               if($_POST['username'] == 'username')
               {
                   if($_POST['pass'] == 'password')
                   {

                      $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                      header('Location:index.php');

                    }
               }
               }
       ?>
```

Login Form:

```
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> </br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Logout PHP code:

```
    <?php 
     session_start();
     session_destroy();
     header('Location:index.php');
     ?>
```

index php code:

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      if($_SESSION['login'] =! true || $_SESSION['login'] == "")
      {
          header('Location:login.php');
      }
    ?>
```

index form code:

```
         <form action="logout.php" method="post">
         <input type="submit" name="logout" value="logout" />
         </form>
```

The PHP code is listed above the html code before anything is displayed thus why some form actions call back the page again. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is the incorrect operator `=!` in `index.php` -- the correct use is `!=` for "does not equal". See more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

You can clean up your login.php file a bit:

*login.php*

```
session_start();
$redirect = false;
if($_SESSION['login'] == true) {
    $redirect = true;
} elseif (
    isset($_POST['username']) && 
    $_POST['username'] == 'username' && 
    $_POST['pass'] == 'password'
){
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $redirect = true;
}
if ($redirect) {
    header("location:http://www.mydomain.com/index.php");
    die();
}
```

Your login form is fine, except where you use `:` for properties. All HTML element properties are `name="value"` -- note the equal sign. So your form:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
```

You have it correct in your logout form.

One of your goals is to reduce the amount of code you use. So if you're going to do the same thing many times, you should try to isolate that piece of code as a class, a function, or simply in another file that you include. To that end, you could put your check for login in a separate file:

*security.php*

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || $_SESSION['login'] !== true) {
    header('location:http://www.mydomain.com/login.php');
    die();
}
```

... then use `require_once` to pull that in on any page where you require the user to be logged in:

*index.php*

```
require_once('security.php');
// the rest of your index.php code here
```

**Documentation**

- PHP comparison operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
- `require_once` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php
- Some basic tips for code reuse - http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tips-for-php-scripts-reuse-code-with-the-include-and-require-functions/5077715

Answer (score 1):

Your Form fields for the login form are bad.

it should read:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> </br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pass" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

also i think your boolean condition

```
if($_SESSION['login'] =! true || $_SESSION['login'] == "")
```

should be

```
if($_SESSION['login'] != true || $_SESSION['login'] == "")
```

Try that, if it doesn't work we'll have another look.

Comment: Sorry I don't see the difference in the answer code you just gave me

Comment: @tdelaney18 1) `=!` is NOT `!=` , 2) `action=` is NOT `action:`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this again :)

Edit: The die() (or exit()) are needed, otherwise PHP keeps processing.

**login.php**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['login']))
{
   // checking if username is transmitted and matching (same for password)
   if (   ( !empty($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] === 'username')
       && ( !empty($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'] === 'password')
      )
   {
      $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
      header('Location:index.php');
      die();
   }      
}
else
{
 // if this matches, we are already loggged in.
 header('Location:index.php');
 die();
}

header('Location:login.php');
die();
```

**logout.php**

```
// check if Session exists, otherwise there is nothing to destroy
if (!empty($_SESSION))
{
unset($_SESSION);
}

header('Location:login.php');
die();
```

**index.php**

```
  session_start();

  // if session doesn't exist we redirect to login
  if(empty($_SESSION['login']))
  {
      header('Location:login.php');
  }
```

Comment: Happily upvoted. I'd just recommend that you add a couple of words describing the changes you made so the OP (and anybody seeing your answer later) would have a better understanding about what's going on.

Comment: Ok, I added some comments. HTH. :)

Comment: Well, you could add 'session autostart' to your php configuration, if wished. That will reduce the need for session_start().

Comment: Yes, commenting is also good. But you see, the best thing you can do explain the CHANGES you made to OP's code. Like you can say "you had `=!` which doesn't mean 'not equal', you should use `!=`"..
But anyway, I think it doesn't matter now, he got his answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, your "Login Form" is incorrect, you need to use '=' instead of ':'.
(Edit: What's with minus rating?)

Also, AFAIR Location must be like `Location: http://www.example.com/index.php`

Comment: I just added some stuff to the answer, what's wrong with that?

Comment: I dont believe there is a problem with : and = in the link redirect I was having problems performing echo right before $_SESSION['login'] = true could there be a problem there?

Comment: The login form `=` instead of `:` is correct however your following statement is incorrect, you would only need a fully specified uri if you were going to a different domain.  His index.php is presumably on the same domain and therefore just using `Location: index.php` is perfectly fine

Comment: @Adnan would you care to explain why you believe this is such a bad answer? Yes there are other problems with the code like `=!` instead of `!=` however the first of his two points was completely valid.

Comment: @Adnan Fair enough the first version of his answer i saw was this "As far as I can see, your "Login Form" is incorrect, you need to use '=' instead of ':'" which explained where the error was and what the error was.  I thought the post was still useful tbh.

Comment: Okay, so I've removed my sarcastic comment, I admit that was wrong. Of course we can be nice and upvote everything and only downvote things with EXTREMELY bad answers. But let's be objective for a second here, the first point lacked explanation and the second point doesn't contribute to the solution of the OP's problem. It doesn't mean I'm a bad person, but just in my opinion the answer isn't useful. I don't know Tobias and I have nothing against him.

Comment: Everything is fine for me, acutally I have to admit that my first answer was a bit sloppy. Thanks to Adnans effort, I made another one.